# $wpdb not being defined in function: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: wpdb

For some reason the $wpdb object is not being defined in one particular function. I have four other functions in the file that are using $wpdb and all are working fine except this one simple delete function where I get the error: ***Call to a member function query() on a non-object...*** The following is the function in question:

```
function delete_gallery( $gallery_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "DELETE from galleries WHERE gallery_id = $gallery_id";
    $deleted = $wpdb->query( $sql );

}
```

I have a link (delete gallery) on the plugin admin settings page that links to delete-gallery.php that calls the delete function and returns back to the admin page. The contents of that file are:

```
include 'ga-functions.php';

if (isset($_GET['gallery_id'])) {
    $gallery_id = $_GET['gallery_id'];
    delete_gallery($gallery_id);

    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    exit();
}
```

If I var_dump on the $wpdb after initializing I get the result of NULL. Anyone have any suggestions on what could be causing this in only one particular function like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, new solution.  First off, I'd recommend making the link a submit button and making the name something unique:

```
<submit name 'del_gallery' />
```

Then in the code of your admin page:

```
include 'ga-functions.php';
//checks to see if certain button was pressed
if(isset($_REQUEST['del_gallery'] && isset($_GET['gallery_id']) ) {     
    $gallery_id = $_GET['gallery_id'];
    delete_gallery($gallery_id);

    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    exit();        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Manny. After adding in the hook I'm getting the error: Call to undefined function add_action()... from the delete-gallery.php file

Comment: Okay, I see why.  You are calling this php file without loading WordPress at all.  That's why `$wpdb` and `add_action` are unavailable.  I added an include to `wp-load.php`, which should sole the problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried that using the 'wp-load.php' but when I do it thows the errors/warnings: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\gallery-admin\includes\delete-gallery.php on line 3 .....AND.....
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\gallery-admin\includes\delete-gallery.php on line 3

Comment: okay, give me a sec and let me see what I can find out.  By the way, is this php file in a plugin or function file?

Comment: it's in a plugin file.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a custom plugin option page?

Comment: I have an anchor link on the plugin admin settings page (gallery-admin.php) that links to delete-gallery.php (the one that you amended above) which does nothing except calls the delete function in 'ga-functions.php' and returns back to the admin page after the db had been updated

Comment: Check new solution, see if that works

Comment: It returns false with the 'if' statement with the post variables that you amended. For the REQUEST post, that should be the 'name' attribute of the anchor that was clicked on the admin page, correct?

Comment: That last solution did the trick. Many thanks for your help and time with this Manny.

Comment: Glad I was able to help